# Kernel Module UDP socket drops datagrams although consumed

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, udp, kernel-module

#### The Situation

I am currently writing a kernel module, that should handle a custom network protocol based on UDP.
What I do (in rather pseudocode) is, I create a UDP socket with

```
sock_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, &sk);
```

where `sk` is the socket pointer.
So, instead of actively polling the kernel for new UDP data, I registered the data ready callback with

```
sk->sk_data_ready = myudp_data_ready;
```

And here is the full code of the `myudp_data_ready` function:

```
void myudp_data_ready(struct sock *sk) {
    struct sk_buff *skb;
    int err;

    if ((skb = skb_recv_datagram(sk, 0, 1, &err)) == NULL) {
        goto Bail;
    }

    // ...
    // HERE, MY CUSTOM UDP-BASED PROTOCOL WILL BE IMPLEMENTED
    // ...

    skb_free_datagram(sk, skb);

    return;
Bail:
    return;
}
```

#### The Problem

The problem now is, that I get all UDP packets perfectly fine.
The `skb_recv_datagram` function is returning a socket buffer that I can handle.
However, after some time, it stops working.

#### What I already tried

In `/proc/net/udp` I can see, that the `rx_queue` is growing until it's full and than packets are dropped.
This is, where I do not get any packets anymore in my code (obviously).
This seems odd.
If I understood correctly, the Kernel uses a reference count in socket buffers.
If this count drops to 1, the buffer is free'd and unlinked from the receive queue.
I had a look in to the `skb->users` field, which is supposed to be the reference count.
It is set to `1`, which means, that my code is the only place holding a reference to the `skb`.
But neither `skb_free_datagram` nor `kfree_skb` seems to free the buffer, as the `rx_queue` keeps growing.
And I have no clue why.
Do you have any advice?
Am I missing something?

#### Some more information

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Kernel version 5.4.0-52.
I have a simple user-land application sending UDP packets to a specific port where the kernel module is listening on.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"If this count drops to 1"* - actually to 0.

Comment: I am having the same issue writing very similar code. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I just solved the problem by using kernel_recvmsg instead. It seems to unlink the packets from the queue(s) correctly